# L298N as LiPo charger

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, battery-charging, lm317

The L298N motor driver contains a voltage regulator (lm317), so is it possible to adjust the output voltage beyond 5V and 12V to charge a 7.4V lithium polymer battery?

Comment: What does make you state `The L298N motor driver contains a voltage regulator`?

Comment: Many Chinese L298 motor driver BOARDS contain a voltage regulator IC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***That's an extremely bad idea.*** Even if the chip contained a voltage regulator like the LM317 (which it doesn't, BTW, see below), the charging process for a Lithium-based cell must be extremely controlled, unless you want to risk the destruction of the cell (and in case of naked cells, you could also risk "venting with flames" accidents).

A lithium cell needs to be charged in different phases. The two main phases are **first a *constant current* (CC) phase**, until the cells reaches the target voltage (a.k.a. *float voltage*: 4.200V±50mV for the most common Li-Mn chemistry), **then there is a *constant voltage* (CV) phase**, where current is monitored until it decreases to about a fraction of the C value of the cell (usually between C/10 and C/20). During the CV phase the voltage must remain constant with ±50mV tolerance or so.

Moreover, if the cell starts being charged when its voltage is below some minimum value (e.g. 3.5V) it needs to be "precharged" with a constant current that is much less than the normal charging current in the CC phase, until it reaches the threshold voltage.

On top of all that, the control logic of the charger must ensure that the cell voltage is not below some absolute minimum (e.g. 2V), under which the cell should be considered permanently damaged, because if you tried to charge a cell that has become so discharged its internal structure has changed so much that charging it becomes dangerous.

Any attempt to charge the cell outside all those limits will either result in an underperforming cell (less charge stored, much more energy wasted to charge it to a certain level), or in a damaged cell. A damaged cell could simply lose part of its capacity permanently or, in the worst case, become susceptible to **leakage or venting during usage or charging, which is very dangerous for any lithium-based cell.**

A quite old, but still meaningful, application note from Texas Instruments about battery charging is [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva557/snva557.pdf). It's an application note for older charger chips, but the theory about charging is still relevant today and it is explained fairly well.

---

That's why even cheap-ass chargers use a dedicated chip that automates such procedures. An example is the ubiquitous and extremely cheap [TP4056](http://toppwr.com/uploadfile/file/20230304/640301eae1260.pdf) from the Chinese [Top Power ASIC Corporation](http://toppwr.com/eindex.php). That's a chip suitable for single-cell Li-Mn (Lithium-Manganese, probably the most common chemistry today in consumer products) batteries.

There are even cheap charger modules sold on Amazon or other platforms based on that chip, for example [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LTQU2RK) (the first I found on Amazon):

[image]

Moreover if a battery pack contains multiple cells in series it becomes necessary to charge the cells individually, to avoid unbalances in the charging status of the cells. This requires even more advanced chips to build a Battery Management System (BMS) circuit to be embedded in the battery pack.

---

As for the L298 containing an LM317 or any other kind or regulator like it, this is wrong. Here is the internal schematic of that chip, taken from [its datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf):

[image]

As you can see the chip contains two complete full H-bridges made up with BJTs and the relative control logic. The only thing that resembles a "regulator" is the block named Vref which is a low-power voltage reference used to power the internal logic circuit and set their logic thresholds (note that it is connected to the Vss pin, which is the *Logic Supply Voltage* according to the table at page 2).

So there is no way you can get from that chip a regulated DC output suitable to charge a single lithium cell, let alone to implement the complex algorithm needed for its safe charging.

BTW, as a side note, the L298 is an old dinosaur. It still uses BJTs to implement H-bridges instead of MOSFETs and it is hugely inefficient because of this. It's only advantage is it is ubiquitous in modules for hobby markets and that makes it dirty cheap (a marginal advantage is its moderately high limit for the motor voltage, i.e. 50V, which makes it quite robust for the price).